# R language to writing long texts?

Tags: r, email, text

I'm bothering you here again with a stupid question after unsuccessfully googleing for a while. I need to send A TON (hundreds) of personalized emails.
I know it is possible to send emails using R, but all the packages I've checked so far require something like `body = "Body of the email"`, that is, they work with fixed pre-established text as the body text of the email.
But, again, I need to personalize them. For example, let's have the following text:

"When  Mr.  Bilbo  Baggins  of  Bag  End  announced  that  he would  shortly  be  celebrating  his  eleventy-first  birthday  with a  party  of  special  magnificence,  there  was  much  talk  and excitement  in  Hobbiton.

Bilbo  was  very  rich  and  very  peculiar,  and  had  been  the wonder  of  the  Shire  for  sixty  years,  ever  since  his  remarkable disappearance  and  unexpected  return.  The  riches  he  had brought  back  from  his  travels  had  now  become  a  local  legend, and  it  was  popularly  believed,  whatever  the  old  folk  might say,  that  the  Hill  at  Bag  End  was  full  of  tunnels  stuffed  with treasure.  And  if  that  was  not  enough  for  fame,  there  was  also his  prolonged  vigour  to  marvel  at.  Time  wore  on,  but  it seemed  to  have  little  effect  on  Mr.  Baggins.  At  ninety  he  was much  the  same  as  at  fifty.  At  ninety-nine  they  began  to  call him  well-preserved,  but  unchanged  would  have  been  nearer  the mark.  There  were  some  that  shook  their  heads  and  thought this  was  too  much  of  a  good  thing;  it  seemed  unfair  that anyone  should  possess  (apparently)  perpetual  youth  as  well as  (reputedly)  inexhaustible  wealth."

that is, a text with a couple of paragraphs. And let's have the following receivers `c("Gandalf", "Saruman", "Sauron")`, what I want is to create personalized texts for my emails combining both, headered:

"Dear Gandalf,

When  Mr.  Bilbo  Baggins  of  Bag  End... [all the aforementioned text]"

I have tried stuff like:

```rs
txt <- "When  Mr.  Bilbo  Baggins  of  Bag  End... [all the aforementioned text]" 
for(i in 1:length(rs)){
     temp <- paste("Dear", rs[i], txt) 
}
```

I have also tried calling this text from a .txt file and the idea is to use it then as `body = temp`. But I only get "unnatural" texts, with continuous lines, symbols, "", etc.
Any idea regarding how to solve this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Why aren’t you just using `paste`?

Comment: This is just one the several stuff I've tried so far, @IRTF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sprintf`, which allows you to have placeholders that are then substituted:

```
lapply(c("Gandalf", "Saruman", "Sauron"), 
       sprintf, 
       fmt = "Dear %s,

When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End... [all the aforementioned text]")

#[[1]]
#[1] "Dear Gandalf,\n\nWhen Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End... [all the aforementioned #text]"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "Dear Saruman,\n\nWhen Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End... [all the aforementioned #text]"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "Dear Sauron,\n\nWhen Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End... [all the aforementioned #text]"
```

Use `mapply` instead of `lapply` if you need to substitute more then one string. Or use a `for` loop if you prefer.

Comment: As can be seen in your answer @Roland, your script results in a weird text. I need a "natural" text (that is: no commands, symbols, quotation marks, etc.) to include in the body of the emails.

Comment: @perep1972 No, it doesn't. This is not "weird" but perfectly normal. R will always `print` a linebreak in a character string as `\n`. It is the responsibility of the function/software displaying the text to the user to display linebreaks as linebreaks and most software can do that just fine (in R you could use `cat`). Have you tried sending this text as an email (to yourself)?